# 'int' has no attribute 'conn' minecraft api

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, minecraft

I'm starting out with the minecraft api largely for school but also out of curiosity. When I run the code below, I get the error `'int' object has no attribute 'conn'` for the spot I have labeled

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft

mc=Minecraft

i=0
for x in range(-128,128):
    for z in range(-128,128):
        for y in range(-64,mc.getHeight(x,z)): #right here
            mc.setBlock(x,y,z,0)
        i+=1
        print(str(i/(256*256))+'% complete')
```

Comment: It looks like you not creating the MineCraft object -- 
mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()
Or, specify ip address and port
mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create("192.168.1.1", 4711)

Comment: @fiacre could you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct cause someone else is gonna miss it too at some point

Comment: Sure thing, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Minecraft documentation:

```
.create(address = "localhost", port = 4711)
"Create connection to Minecraft (address, port) => Minecraft object"
#use default address and port
mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()
#specify ip address and port
mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create("192.168.1.1", 4711)
```

Then mc.getHeight(x,z) will return an integer.